# How to enable search without keyword?

Tags: search

I have core search in my site. When I search without entering any keyword there is following warning message fired;

> Please enter some keywords.

I just want to show all available results without firing any warning message.

**Note:** I don't want to use any extra module, or create a view with the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module, for this tiny task. I just want to alter the existing site search.